# Parse Tree building

Tags: parsing

I am trying to learn how to build parse trees. 
This is a very simple example as I am hoping I can catch on to the concept. 
$\mathtt{y=x+z}$

Wouldn't this simply require $\mathtt{(term) = (term) + (term)}$?
I'm not sure how to express my answer on here but would it only require one branch due to the $\mathtt{=}$ sign?

Comment: That would depend on your grammar.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it's

[image]

since you first add x and z and then assign the result to y.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the [Shunting-Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)? If not, you may want to give it a shot.